# Tensorflow 2.2.0 Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.7'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I've successfully installed CUDA10.1, then cudnn7.6.5 finally copied libcudnn.so.7 to /usr/lib/cuda/lib64, and exported lib64 folder to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. However I still get the error in tensorflow:

pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1050 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.493GHz coreCount: 5 deviceMemorySize: 3.95GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 104.43GiB/s
2021-04-23 19:22:22.552489: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2021-04-23 19:22:22.553662: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2021-04-23 19:22:22.554817: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-04-23 19:22:22.555015: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-04-23 19:22:22.556229: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-04-23 19:22:22.556901: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2021-04-23 19:22:22.557021: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] **Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.7'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/cuda/include:/usr/lib/cuda/lib64:**
2021-04-23 19:22:22.557031: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1598] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...

finally I did: ldconfig /usr/lib/cuda/lib64, but still no luck. Very much appreciate a solution!

Comment: Several workarounds are discussed in [ImportError: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20271) may help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow expect the reference libcudnn.so.7 to be a symbloic link to the actual shared object e.g lidcudnn.so.7.6.5

If libcudnn.so and libcudnn.so.xx are not symlinks then this is the reason why you got this error.

I found the solution for this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025928/why-do-i-get-sbin-ldconfig-real-usr-local-cuda-lib64-libcudnn-so-7-is-not-a)!